# Can't Apply Chinese Language through Resource File ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, cultureinfo, currentuiculture

when i use this code it should be changing the Language of the Site but in case of chinese it wont work

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["Lang"] = langId;
string langCode = "";
switch (langId)
{
    case 0:
        langCode = "ar-SA";
        break;
    case 1:
        langCode = "en-US";
        break;
    case 2:
        langCode = "fr-FR";
        break;
    case 3:
        langCode = "fa-IR";
        break;
    case 5:
        langCode = "ru-RU";
        break;
    case 6:
        langCode = "zh-CN";
        break;

}
CultureInfo language = new CultureInfo(langCode);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = language;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = language;
```

Note that the resource file name for chinese language is SPA_Resource.zh.resx

What is wrong here ???

Comment: Try using `SPA_Resource.zh-cn.resx` as the filename

Comment: well i did :( but not working notice that also i faced a problem with the russian wont wort till i name the file SPA_Resource.RU.resx ru in upper case i dont know why

Comment: Uhm, I don't know for asp.net, but in WPF, using the general culture wouldn't work for chinese (in some simple tests), but using the specific `zh-cn.resx` did work. Maybe try `zh-CN.resx` if it's case sensitive for any reason?